# Pull data from Webservice in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, tooltip

I have three different options in the middle of my page and basically when a user hovers over any of them it want it to pull data through from my Web-service and display. I wanted it to be displayed like a tool tip next to the label.

Is this possible to achieve, if not what thing can i do?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just put your 'different options' in an update panel and, when the user hovers over any of them, use javascript to click a button that is a trigger for the Update Panel - and go and get the data you want to display.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Thanks I will try and put that into practice now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any details about your code, I'll be quick as well:

AJAX

Comment: I'm asking help of how to achieve something. I don't have an code because I don't know how to do it? How is Ajax going to help me? What part of Ajax should I use? I don't want you to do any code i want to know what would be best to use.